# Charges in a molecule and rotation invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why are the charges of atoms in a molecule not invariant under the rotations of the molecule?

My intuition is that the charges should not change under the rotation of the molecule, because their relative positions do not change. But I was told that they can change.

Comment: What do you mean? Molecules can have unsymmetrical charge distributions.

Comment: Try drawing a picture of a water molecule. Now turn that picture upside down.